# Where to put ajax request in Ember tutorial app?

Tags: ajax, ember.js

I want to add "Weather: 24C" to the `rental-listing` component of the `super-rentals` [tutorial app](https://github.com/ember-learn/super-rentals).

Where would be the "best-practices" place to put this ajax request?

```
Ember.$.getJSON(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${location}&APPID=${apiKey}`)
    .then(function(json) {
      return JSON.parse(json).main.temp;
  });
```

Do I need to add a component, add a model, add a service, add a second adapter, modify the existing adapter? Something else? All of these? Is the problem that the tutorial uses Mirage? I ask this because when I think I'm getting close, I get an error like this:

```
Mirage: Your Ember app tried to GET
'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&APPID=5432',
     but there was no route defined to handle this request.
     Define a route that matches this path in your
     mirage/config.js file. Did you forget to add your namespace?
```

Comment: I think the problem is almost definitely Mirage related. I'm not quite sure where the optimal place for the ajax request is though as I've never written hard AJAX into an ember application of mine. When you get that error, where are you placing the AJAX request?

Comment: I would suggest that any fetch for outside data should live inside the model hook of a route. I also agree with @Wilddog that the problem you are experiencing is mirage related. The ajax request is being made but not handled.

Comment: @Wilddog I have tried it from several places. In fact, I tried it from everywhere I could imagine ... from its own component, from in the rental-listing component, from a service, tried making a model, adapter, etc. Currently I have it in the rental model (models/rental.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure mirage to allow you making calls to outside in case mirage is active; what I mean is using `this.passthrough` function within `mirage/config.js`, that is explained in [api documentation](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.3.x/configuration/) quite well.

Regarding your question about where to make the remote call is; it depends:

- If you need the data from the server to arrive in case a route is about to open; you should prefer putting it within `model` hook of the corresponding `route`.
- If you intend to develop a component that is to be reused from within different routes or even from within different applications with the same remote call over and over again; you can consider putting the ajax remote call to a component. Even if  that is not a very common case usually; it might be the case that a component itself should be wrapped up to fetch the data and display it by itself for reusing in different places; there is nothing that prevents you to do so. However by usually applying data-down action-up principle; generally the remote calls fall into routes or controllers.
- Whether using an `ember-data` `model` is another thing to consider. If you intend to use `ember-data`; you should not directly use `Ember.$.ajax` but rather be using `store` provided by `ember-data` and perhaps providing your custom adapter/serializer to convert data to the format `ember-data` accepts in case the server do not match to the formats that `ember-data` accepts. In summary; you do not need to use `model`s if you use pure ajax as you do in this question.

Comment: Thanks, that's just the kind of answer I was hoping for regarding where make the remote call. And you're an "Ember.js newbie"? :)

Comment: As for the config for Mirage to allow remote calls to the network layer, I had actually already tried several combinations of passthrough, namespace, and urlPrefix but none worked. Based on the documentation you linked to, I need a namespace and then a passthrough at the end of the config file. But any idea why even that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @Chroaster thanks for reminding me for updating my profile :) I will try to prepare a twiddle for you regarding mirage asap.

Comment: well apparently openweather does not provide https endpoint and you cannot make http requests from within ember twiddle. anyway; can you put the following to your `miraga/config.js` file: `'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/**` I expect it to work without any problems.

Comment: In the end, the only line I needed to add to `mirage/config.js` was `this.passthrough('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/**');` which works both before and after the other namespace and mock data.

Like you said, the documentation does spell it all out, but the error message suggested adding a namespace, not ignoring namespaces altogether passthrough. So I think that's why I never tried just passthrough with an explicit url.

Comment: And regarding the placement of the ajax request itself, I ended up putting it in a service that a weather component uses, the same way the tutorial did it for the map component. Though I have a feeling your third option would be the right way to do it, I don't know. Is it always better to use `ember-data`?

Comment: not necessarily; `ember-data` is an add-on to ease the way of communication between client side and server side; it also provides kind of a persistence layer through `store` service. i am working as a front end developer of a big enterprise project for a year and a half now. we have about 10 micro-front ends (10 different ember applications); but we decided not to go with `ember-data`. it is not a must; but most of the ember community like it and use it.